# How to consume chuncks from ConcurrentQueue correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer, tpl-dataflow

I need to implement a queue of requests which can be populated from multiple threads. When this queue becomes larger than 1000 completed requests, this requests should be stored into database. Here is my implementation:

```
public class RequestQueue
{
    private static BlockingCollection<VerificationRequest> _queue = new BlockingCollection<VerificationRequest>();
    private static ConcurrentQueue<VerificationRequest> _storageQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<VerificationRequest>();

    private static volatile bool isLoading = false;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static void Launch()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(execute);
    }

    public static void Add(VerificationRequest request)
    {
        _queue.Add(request);
    }

    public static void AddRange(List<VerificationRequest> requests)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(requests, new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3},
            (request) => { _queue.Add(request); });
    }


    private static void execute()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5}, EnqueueSaveRequest );
    }

    private static void EnqueueSaveRequest(VerificationRequest request)
    {
        _storageQueue.Enqueue( new RequestExecuter().ExecuteVerificationRequest( request ) );
        if (_storageQueue.Count > 1000 && !isLoading)
        {
            lock ( _lock )
            {
                if ( _storageQueue.Count > 1000 && !isLoading )
                {
                    isLoading = true;

                    var requestChunck = new List<VerificationRequest>();
                    VerificationRequest req;
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    {
                        if( _storageQueue.TryDequeue(out req))
                            requestChunck.Add(req);
                    }
                    new VerificationRequestRepository().InsertRange(requestChunck);

                    isLoading = false;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Is there any way to implement this without lock and isLoading?

Comment: Why don't you want to use lock? I mean it seems not affect perfomance in any way in this case.

Comment: I agree, but maybe there is a better way. Also i'm not sure that i implement locking with isLoading correctly

Comment: Why do you even need `isLoading`? What would change if you simply remove it?

Comment: to prevent waiting of lock when we've already started storing

Comment: Use TPL Dataflow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194745(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why do you even have two concurrent data structures? Just have a single thread doing the reading, when it gets to 1000 elements or when the list is full in a local List it can output the current list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you ask is to use the blocks in the [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) library. Eg

```
var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<VerificationRequest>(1000);
var exportBlock = new ActionBlock<VerificationRequest[]>(records=>{
               new VerificationRequestRepository().InsertRange(records);
};

batchBlock.LinkTo(exportBlock , new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

That's it.

You can send messages to the starting block with

```
batchBlock.Post(new VerificationRequest(...));
```

Once you finish your work, you can take down the entire pipeline and flush any leftover messages by calling `batchBlock.Complete();` and await for the final block to finish:

```
batchBlock.Complete();
await exportBlock.Completion;
```

The [BatchBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194745(v=vs.110).aspx) batches up to 1000 records into arrays of 1000 items and passes them to the next block. An [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) uses 1 task only by default, so it is thread-safe. You could use an existing instance of your repository without worrying about cross-thread access:

```
var repository=new VerificationRequestRepository();
var exportBlock = new ActionBlock<VerificationRequest[]>(records=>{
               repository.InsertRange(records);
};
```

Almost all blocks have a concurrent input buffer. Each block runs on its own TPL task, so each step runs concurrently with each other. This means that you get asynchronous execution "for free" and can be important if you have multiple linked steps, eg you use a [TransformBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782(v=vs.110).aspx) to modify the messages flowing through the pipeline.

I use such pipelines to create pipelines that call external services, parse responses, generate the final records, batch them and send them to the database with a block that uses SqlBulkCopy.